# Copy file to directory while appending date to the filename

Tags: ubuntu-mate

I would like to copy a file to another directory but with the date embedded within that file name.

Ex. cookies.sqlite -> 6_6_20.cookies.sqlite

This is a modified script I found, but I honestly do not know how much of it operates.

When it is run, I get

cp: cannot stat '': No such file or directory

```
#!/bin/bash
# this is FF profile directory /home/andy/.mozilla/firefox/9r99csdk.default/
## Get current date ##
now1=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")

## Appending a current date from a $_now to a filename stored in $_file ##
file="/home/andy/.mozilla/firefox/9r99csdk.default/$_now1cookies.sqlite"

cp "$_file" /home/andy/Downloads
```

6/8/20

This creates the correct filename, but the file is empty?

```
cp /home/andy/.mozilla/firefox/9r99csdk.default/cookies.sqlite /home/andy/Downloads/$(date +"%m_%d_%Y").cookies.sqlite
```

Comment: `$_file` is not the same thing as `$file`

Comment: I took out the _.  cp: cannot stat '/home/andy/.mozilla/firefox/9r99csdk.default/.sqlite': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Aside from some typos, you appear to be trying to use the *new* filename as the *source* of the `cp` command, rather than its destination. Try

```
cp "/home/andy/.mozilla/firefox/9r99csdk.default/cookies.sqlite" "/home/andy/Downloads/${now1}cookies.sqlite"
```

Note the use of braces around the variable expansion to distinguish `${now1}cookies` from `$now1cookies`

Comment: I appreciate your help. But I do not understand what you are saying. It might be easier to copy it to another directory and then rename it and copy it back.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /home/andy/.mozilla/firefox/9r99csdk.default/
cp cookies.sqlite $(date +"%m_%d_%Y").cookies.sqlite
mv *.cookies.sqlite /home/andy/Maxtor_Backups/
```

Thanks for everyone's help.